# How to handle input string ending in \"

Tags: c, string, escaping

I've just recently delved into C programming at school and have run into a snag with one of my test cases for my program. It's a tokenizer and i'm running it from linux terminal with:

```
./tk "(delimiters)" "(String to be tokenized)"
```

The problem i'm having is how to handle having double quotes in the input in the program itself without having the user to type \". A related problem, a string ending in \ creates a problem as well. Whenever either of these two things happen the program just hangs and doesn't do anything.

I've tried putting a printf right in the first line of main, and even that doesn't run apparently.

Comment: I think using `''` will work.

Comment: To clarify @Jori's comment, '(delimeters)' would be valid and '(foo"a"bar)' would be too. The single quotes means do not interpolate variables. `./tk "($my_delimiters)"` would try to use the `$my_delimiters` variable. `./tk '($my_delimiters)'` would pass `'($my_delimiters)` straight to `./tk`.

Comment: Yeah, only drawback is you can't use `'`. But I'm not entirely sure what he means by `the input in the program itself`...

Comment: So there's no way to be able to use whatever you're wrapping the string in inside the string itself?

Comment: I suspect the reason that the program hangs when you try to printf is that you need to fflush stdout or manually add a newline to what you're trying to printf.  Also, the quotes are interpreted by your shell and not making it into the program.  You might be able to change a shell option to get the behaviour you're looking for.  Aside from that, using escaped quotes as well as outer quotes looks like the only way.  If you're willing to open a file as input instead of using program arguments you could read quotes without escaping them.